# Mysql Range Query

Tags: mysql, range, gaps-and-islands

I have the following Data in a table and need output in range wise IN MYSQL

[image: Table Data]

**OUTPUT:**

[image: OutPUT]

Comment: Not really ranges, which tend to be fixed, but contiguous values lumped together.

Comment: This is known as a [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem, for what it's worth.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Something procedural like a procedure and a cursor(argh) would work